# Calculate timestamp difference in microseconds using Python

Tags: python-2.7

The timestamps are obtained by recording the current time. 
The python script I have right now is ...

sec1 = float(time.time()*1000000)

sec2 = float(time.time()* 1000000)

print(sec1)

print(sec2)

print(sec2 - sec1)

I am not sure if my approach is correct and I don't know if time.time is pricise enough. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any actual code already written?  Are you trying to ask how to get the current time *and* calculate the difference?

Comment: Exactly, in microseconds!

Comment: Put what you've tried in the original question instead of the comments please :)

Comment: Other than the fact that `float()` isn't necessary, I believe what you have is correct, but you're at the mercy of your operating system as far as how precise the actual results are going to be.